# How can I pass a Python StringIO() object to a ZipFile(), or is it not supported?

Tags: python, stringio, python-zipfile

I have a [`StringIO()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#cStringIO.StringIO) file-like object, and I am trying to write it to a [`ZipFile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects), but I get this TypeError:

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, cStringIO.StringI found
```

Here is a sample of the code I am using:

```
file_like = StringIO()
archive = zipfile.ZipFile(file_like, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

# my_file is a StringIO object returned by a remote file storage server.
archive.write(my_file)
```

The docs say that [`StringIO()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#cStringIO.StringIO) is a file-like class and that [`ZipFile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects) can accept a file-like object. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The parameter to [`ZipFile.write()`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) is a filename.

Comment: Just found this; is there a typo your second line, or was that your actual code? `ZipFile(file_file` instead of `ZipFile(file_like`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To add a string to a ZipFile you need to use the writestr method and pass the string from StringIO using getvalue method of the StringIO instance

e.g.

```
archive.writestr("name of file in zip", my_file.getvalue())
```

Note you also need to give the name of the string to say where it is placed in the zip file.