# writing StringIO back to disk in python

Tags: python, zip, shutil, stringio

I created an in-memory zip file using `StringIO` and `zipfile`:

```
inMemoryZip = StringIO()
outfile = zipfile.ZipFile(inMemoryZip, 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
//outfile.write(stuff)
inMemoryZip.seek(0)
return inMemoryZip
```

This data is uploaded to a server/database. At some point, it's retrieved and I need to write it to disk as a zip file. I'm not sure how to do this. I tried the following:

```
with open('pathToNewZip.zip', 'w') as archive:
  archive.write(inMemoryZip.getvalue())
```

This creates the zip file archive, but when I double click it, I can't see its contents, it basically creates a duplicate of itself (another identical .zip file, ***but the extension is .zip.cpgz***) next to the original

I also tried:

```
with open('pathToNewZip.zip', 'w') as archive:
      shutil.copyfileobj(inMemoryZip, archive)
```

but its the same result as above.

I guess part of the problem is I don't know how to parse this data. The `inMemoryZip` (which is an instance of `StringIO`) could have multiple files in it.

Is each file written as a new row?

What does `.getvalue()` return? The data for all the files in the `StringIO` instance?

How do I determine the names of the files I zipped up previously so they can be re-created with the same name?

There's this: [How can I pass a Python StringIO() object to a ZipFile(), or is it not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299724/how-can-i-pass-a-python-stringio-object-to-a-zipfile-or-is-it-not-supported) but it looks like that works if theres only 1 file being written at a time. my `StringIO` instance can have 1 file or 10 files.

Comment: Note you should probably be using `open` with `wb` considering ZIP files are a binary format.

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the final file "wb" as suggested by @Kupiakos otherwise you will end up with a corrupted archive. Your other problem is that you need to close the zipfile before using the `StringIO` buffer. The close writes the file catalog to the zipfile. Without that, an unzipper may make assumptions such as this being only one of a multipart zip and do odd things. Nominally, just add `outfile.close()` or put it in a context manager (a `with` clause)

```
def foo():
    inMemoryZip = StringIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(inMemoryZip, 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as output:
        //outfile.write(stuff)
    inMemoryZip.seek(0)
    return inMemoryZip
```

then later

```
with open('pathToNewZip.zip', 'wb') as archive:
  archive.write(inMemoryZip.getvalue())
```

Comment: you're the man! I didn't close the zip file that's why it didn't work. thanks a lot

Comment: at what point did you close the zip file?

Comment: @AlvaroFG -  I could have written that better. Putting the first zipfile creator in a `with` clause did it. When the `with` exits, the zipfile is closed.